# Spring RabbitMQ invalid listener

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I am new in Spring RabbitMQ. I am trying to send my ChatMesssage object to RabbitMQ, but during the configuration of RabbitMQ, i am getting that error below :

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.FatalListenerExecutionException: Invalid listener
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'handleMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@6bced6b0}]
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:348)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:253)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:756)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1257)
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener

RabbitConfiguration Class :

```
@Bean
TopicExchange directExchange(){
    return new TopicExchange(MessagingBusNamespace.CHAT_MESSAGE_TOPIC_EXCHANGE);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(final Queue queue, final Exchange exchange){
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(MessagingBusNamespace.ROUTE_KEY).noargs();
}

@Bean
HTTPChatMessageReceiver receiver(){
    return new HTTPChatMessageReceiver();
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter(){
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver(), "handleMessage");
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                     final MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter){
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(MessagingBusNamespace.CHAT_MESSAGE_QUEUE);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```

handler class :

```
public class HTTPChatMessageReceiver {

   public HTTPChatMessageReceiver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

   public void handleMessage(ChatMessage message) {

   }

}
```

Comment: Is `B` in your modified stacktrace an actual `ChatMessage` ?

Comment: yes it is , first i was separated the packages as my business needs. But to solve the problem , I tried to move ChatMessage class in to the same package with spring configuration classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the problem. The problem was not related with the MessagingListenerAdapter. It was related with how I defined the queue name.
If I declare queue such as "queue.chat", Spring throws the exception above.
When I changed the queue name  from "queue.chat" to "messaginggateway-chat-queue" , the application was successfully started.

Thanks

Comment: if an error occurs in java rabbitmq configuration, you should change the queue name to avoid the problem above. Forexample I  tried to add jsonConverter to my queue but i forgot to add it to rabittemplate. Then an error occured: "Message B object is not found. " . When I fixed it and run it again, I faced to face with same problem. After I changed to queue name or remove the old queue from rabbitmq , I have successfully finished my work.